# Visual studio 2012: 0 of 1 error: No error message shown

Tags: visual-studio-2012, error-list

When I try to build my code in VS 2012 I keep on getting build error; and in the error list it says 0 of 1 error; and no error message is shown there. So basically, I am stuck because I can't find where the error is (if there is actually any). I have tried restarting VS; but no help. The code has been working fine; I only modified the code deleting one of the forms.

Has anybody come across such issue?

Comment: Ok, found the problem. It's the error in the Designer.cs files where the events are hooked up with the event handlers. Since I deleted one of the forms I needed to delete one of the click events and event handler hookups. But I would expect the error to be shown in the errorlist as it normally does.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your errors are being filtered so you only see warnings or messages.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33df3b7a.aspx) is a link which talks about viewing errors and sorting / filtering them.  Make sure you have **Errors** selected or just view all 3 categories.